# How can I retrieve data from excel workbooks stored in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, excel, odata

I am creating a workflow on SharePoint online using SharePoint designer. In it, I would like an action that retrieves the contents of cell(s) in excel workbook in a SharePoint document library.
Please help with idea to achieve this.
I have read a little about using Odata but I am not sure how to go about it. I am new to programming and using web services in workflows.

Comment: Looking for something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496608/read-excel-file-stored-in-sharepoint-document-library

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the reference Charles. However, I am not much on C# and programming. I am hoping to find a less advanced way of achieving the result. Using Odata maybe, I don't know.

Comment: It seems to be possible https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163874.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this quickly, it works just fine and I guess it is what you are looking for (access to Excel table using ODATA):

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/intranet/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/MyLibrary/MyFile.xlsx/Odata/Table1

You can use further ODATA statements such as $select, $filter to do more granular queries.

Please make sure your Excel data area is setup as a Table before your try this. You can get a list of tables available in a workbook simply typing above URL without /Table1 part.